# Twilio Send Reply Message to another Phone

Tags: php

I am try to send message or a copy message to another number to twilio but it does not appear to work

receiver: +12345678

twilio number: +987654321

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
?>
<Response>
  <Message to="<?=$_REQUEST['+987654321']?>">
<?=htmlspecialchars(substr($_REQUEST['From'] . ": " . $_REQUEST['Body'], 0, 1600))?>
  </Message>
</Response>
```

Request URL

```
http://domain.com/twillio.php?PhoneNumber=%2B12345678
```

Reference
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-forward-my-sms-messages-to-another-phone-number

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to double check your number formatting, especially if you're using [international numbers](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/how-do-i-format-phone-numbers-to-work-internationally).

You can check them against the [lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups) using curl as in the following example:

```
curl -XGET "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/55-11-5525-6325?Type=carrier&Type=caller-name" -u "{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}"
```